# PyMongo: unable to list collections of database

Tags: python, flask, collections, pymongo

Below is the piece of the code:

```
client=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db1=client.achievements_new
collection=db1.collections

@app.route("/achievements", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def achievements():
    form = Achievements()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        uname=request.form['username']

        achievements=request.form['acheivements1']
        db1.collection.insert_one({'user':uname,'achievements':achievements})


        flash('Your achievements have been added successfully!','success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('achievements.html', title='Achievements', form=form)
```

Form is getting submitted successfully,but in python interpreter if i am trying to list collections,it is throwing error; but database is shown in the list;
below is response of python interpreter

```
from flaskblog import client
print(client.list_database_names())

['achievements', 'achievements_new', 'admin', 'config', 'local', 'mydatabase', 'test']
print(collections.list_collection_names())
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'collections' is not defined
print(db1.list_collection_names())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'db1' is not defined
print(collection.list_collection_names())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'collection' is not defined
print(collections.list_collection_names())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'collections' is not defined
```

I tried all possible combinations, but got nothing fruitful in return.
Any solution for the same would be of great help.

Thanks!!

Comment: in the interpreter are you importing db1 or collection? Or re-running:
db1=client.achievements_new
collection=db1.collections